# Make macro independent, to be used for generating a graph in multiple sheets in excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am rookie when it comes to VBA but essentially I want to create a macro that I can then use to run in multiple sheets. I have a lot of data.

What I have done so far is used the macro recording capability in excel to make the graph and then saving it. This works fine and my graph is generated every time its run on the same sheet. However, when I try to run it in a different sheet, it just generates a graph from the previous sheet. I have looked online and tried to edit the source name to ActiveSheet! but it hasn't worked. Here is my code:

Min ret save

Sub minret_v1()
'
' minret_v1 Macro
'

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""0"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
    "='20160916 Acell 1'!$A$6:$A$1033"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='20160916 Acell 1'!$B$6:$B$1033"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""50"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = _
    "='20160916 Acell 1'!$A$6:$A$1033"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = _
    "='20160916 Acell 1'!$D$953:$D$1033"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='20160916 Acell 1'!$D$6:$D$1033"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "=""100"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).XValues = _
    "='20160916 Acell 1'!$A$6:$A$1033"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = "='20160916 Acell 1'!$F$6:$F$1033"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Name = "=""150"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).XValues = _
    "='20160916 Acell 1'!$A$6:$A$1033"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Values = "='20160916 Acell 1'!$H$6:$H$1033"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Name = "=""200"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).XValues = _
    "='20160916 Acell 1'!$A$6:$A$1033"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Values = "='20160916 Acell 1'!$J$6:$J$1033"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(6).Name = "=""250"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(6).XValues = _
    "='20160916 Acell 1'!$A$6:$A$1033"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(6).Values = "='20160916 Acell 1'!$L$6:$L$1033"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(7).Name = "=""300"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(7).XValues = _
    "='20160916 Acell 1'!$A$6:$A$1033"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(7).Values = "='20160916 Acell 1'!$N$6:$N$1033"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(8).Name = "=""350"""
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(8).XValues = _
    "='20160916 Acell 1'!$A$6:$A$1033"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(8).Values = "='20160916 Acell 1'!$P$6:$P$1033"
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 993
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 987
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 970
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 945
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 897
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 761
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 494
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 431
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 356
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 237
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 214
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 165
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 142
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 109
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 89
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 80
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 52
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 46
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 38
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 37
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 35
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 34
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 32
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 31
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 29
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 28
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 25
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 16
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 8
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
    "C:\Users\Santiago\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\Mult Lines_decay.crtx" _
    )
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "gamma(nm)"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "gamma(nm)"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 9).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 9).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoTrue
    .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .Size = 18
    .Italic = msoFalse
    .Kerning = 12
    .Name = "Arial"
    .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Select
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = _
    "Distance from interaction"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
    "Distance from interaction"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 25).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 25).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoTrue
    .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .Size = 18
    .Italic = msoFalse
    .Kerning = 12
    .Name = "Arial"
    .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Acell 20160916"
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Acell 20160916"
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 14).ParagraphFormat
    .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
    .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
End With
With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 14).Font
    .BaselineOffset = 0
    .Bold = msoTrue
    .NameComplexScript = "Arial"
    .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
    .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    .Fill.Transparency = 0
    .Fill.Solid
    .Size = 21.6
    .Italic = msoFalse
    .Kerning = 12
    .Name = "Arial"
    .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
    .Strike = msoNoStrike
End With
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
Range("R10").Select
```

End Sub

If anyone can help me it would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the macro as an Add-in. It is then available when you start excel.
You can also distribute the Add-in.

Otherwise, you can add the macro to your personal book.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566